# Trying to be concise in JavaScript with null coalescing and not figuring it out

Tags: javascript

I often write code like this after I retrieve a block of data, typically from a JSON server. I do it to check for either no data or bad data and then I don't have to check in all the code directly below it.  My code always looks like this:

```js
if (!(response && response.data && response.data.length > 0)) {
    return something nullish or whatever is appropriate
}
```

Is there a clean way with newer JavaScript to do this? I don't think changing &&'s to ||'s does the trick, but not sure.

Comment: `(response?.data?.length ?? 0) > 0` -- something like this maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Optional chaining can solve your problem.

```
response?.data?.length
```

Comment: Does that turn to 0 if any of them are undefined (or undefined or something else)

Comment: @Pete, no, it will return undefined if reference is undefined or null